# php: regex remove bracket in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

similiar like this example, [php: remove brackets/contents from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336672/php-remove-brackets-contents-from-a-string) i have no idea to replace

```
$str = '(ABC)some text'
```

into

```
$str = 'ABC';
```

currently use `$str = preg_replace('/(.)/','',$str);` but not works. how to fix this?

Comment: all works! which one should i choose? which is the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use replace, you could use the following:

```
 $str = "(ABC)some text";
 $str = preg_replace("/^.*\(([^)]*)\).*$/", '$1', $str);
```

The pattern will match the whole string, and replace it with whatever it found inside the parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

Instead of preg_replace, I would use preg_match:

```
preg_match('#\(([^)]+)\)#', $str, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Comment: Realistically, this is a more clear cut case for matching on a string rather than replacing a string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Start each line with 4 spaces to format it as code - http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Also,there's no need to sign your post.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using regex altogether here. Instead, you could use normal string functions like this:
$str = str_replace(array('(',')'),array(),$str);

Comment: thanks user366075, but this not remove *some text* at the end of bracket. only wants string in bracket and remove others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\((.*?)\).*/','\\1',$str);
```