# php preg_match between bracket

Tags: php, string, preg-match

i want to use preg_match to find text between bracket for example: `$varx = "(xx)";`

final output will be `$match = 'xx';`

another example `$varx = "bla bla (yy) bla bla";`

final output will be something like this `$match = 'yy';`

in other words it strips out bracket. i'm still confusing with regular expression but found that sometimes preg match is more simple solution. searching other example but not meet my need.

Comment: You can try match tests here: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: What's wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035258/php-regex-remove-bracket-in-string/3035343#3035343) from a question that _you_ asked which results in the **exact** same thing?

Comment: @Herbert - sorry i have search before submit. forgot the question and solution. maybe previous question is not meet search keywords. previous entry was removing other character and this one find character inside bracket. the result is same both of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $subject, $match);
```

Now it will capture newlines.

Comment: This is good as long as their are no line breaks between parentheses.

Comment: He never said he was expecting any.

Comment: like if someone hits 'enter' while typing in the `(` and `)`

Comment: i select first working regex match. thank you for all your ideas and comments. sorry for late reply because my internet connection down. :)

Answer (score 8):

Bear in mind that brackets are special characters in RegExps so you'll need to escape them with a backslash - you've also not made it clear as to what possible range of characters can appear between `( ... )` or whether there can be multiple instances of `( ... )`.

So, your best bet might be a RegExp like: `/\(([^\)]*)\)/` which will match many occurrences of `( ... )` containing **any** (or no) characters between the parentheses.

Try `preg_match('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $sString, $aMatches)`

EDIT: (example)

```
<?php
$sString = "This (and) that";
preg_match_all('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $sString, $aMatches);
echo $aMatches[1][0];
echo "\n\n\n";
print_r($aMatches);
?>
```

Which results in:

```
and


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (and)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => and
        )

)
```

So the string "and" is stored in $aMatches[1][0] :)

Comment: how to remove ( and ) in your example?

Comment: nps: actually make it preg_match_all for _many_ occurrences which will give you a multidimensional array - otherwise you'll only get one occurrence back on `$aMatches[1]` ;)

Comment: Say your string is "This (and) that" and you want to retrieve "and" then the result in $aMatches from `preg_match_all('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $sString, $aMatches)` _should_ be in `$aMatches[1][1]` ... I think : http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: i just want to return word "and"

Answer (score 4):

`preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/i', $varx, $match);`

Adding the `s` modifier allows line-breaks between parentheses. For example:

`bla bla (y`
`y) bla bla`

`preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/si', $varx, $match);`

A better expression can be constructed if the content between paraentheses has a regular pattern. For example, if it were always double letters like xx or yy, the following expression would be a better match.

`/\(([a-zA-Z]{2})\)/i`

Also, if you want to capture *all* matches in `$varx`, use `preg_match_all()`. For example:

`this (and) that (or) the other`

`preg_match_all()` will capture `and` and `or`

To test it use something like:

```
<?php
$varx = "this (and) that (or) the other";
preg_match_all('/\((.*?)\)/si', $varx, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This will show where the matches are in the `$matches` array.

Comment: This captures the `(` and `)` too. It looks like he didn't want them.

Comment: I thought of a way for the `preg_match_all()` to work without capturing the `(` and `)`. This this: 

`'/(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))/i'`

add the `s` to the end if you need newlines too.

Comment: @Biotox: That's pretty cool. I forgot about `?:`. That would certainly clean up the results a bit. You should add it to your answer. I'd be happy to upvote it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works

```
preg_match_all('#\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)#x');
```

I'm sorry for the incomplete answer..

> ```
> $preg_match = '#\(((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*\)#x';
>
> $data = 'bla bla (yy) bla bla';
>
> if(preg_match_all($preg_match, $data, $match)) {
>     $match = $match[0];
> } else {
>     $match = array();
> }
> ```

Hope is makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

This seems cleaner.

```
$pattern = '/\((.+?)\)/is';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regex for this, use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $your_string);
```

Comment: Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given

Comment: @apis17: please, just refresh my answer